# How can I cancel a tab selection?

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I'm using a TabLayout in an Activity. I'd like to prompt the user and then save some data on that tab when the user leaves the tab.

The save process will take several seconds and a visual progress bar is needed, during that time, I'd like to stay in the data tab.

Is there any way to cancel the tab selection? Is `onTabUnselected` too late to stop the tab switch?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to that?